# I need to call apex method from custom button.I am using following code and getting error

Tags: apex

**====code=====**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/apex.js")} 

try{ 
var recordId ={!Case.Id}; 

var result = sforce.apex.execute("CreateOpportunityOnCase", "createOpportunityOnClickOfButton",{recordId : "recordId"}); 
location.reload(true); 

} 
catch(ex) { 
alert(ex); 
}
```

**====errror==========**

```
{faultCode:soapenvClient,No such parameter recordid definrd for Operation,check your WSDL FILE}
```

**=========cOMMENTS===========**

i DO NOT KNOE ABOUT wsdl file.what is this and how to check that.

Comment: in js always use merge fields in single quotes  `var recordId = '{!Case.Id}';`

Answer (score 0):

This is case sensitivity problem, check **Id** and **id** both are different

mark it if helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Few days ago i was also stuck on this.. I use a visualforce page and call the class from command button on visualforce page instead of custom button and include that vf in page layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/connection.js")} {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/apex.js")}

try {
var result = JSON.parse(sforce.apex.execute("CreateOpportunityOnCase","createOpportunityOnClickOfButton",{recordId : "{!Case.Id}"})); location.reload(true);
}
catch(ex) {
    alert(ex);
}
```